# Email and Phone Number validation App Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-apps, email-validation

I am using this to validate email address from html page for a web app in Google Scripts. It is not validating and allowing wrong email entry.

```
<input id="email" type="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$" class="validate valid" required>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to use them both Type="email" or pattern at the same time as this might induce a clash in browsers that support both features. Using type="email" has the advantage that it is semantically correct both using the pattern attribute has the advantage that there are several easy-to-use polyfills on the web which ensures support for a greater range of audience.
Try this with improved regex:

```
<input pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/" required />
```

Or

```
<input type="email" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to put slashes around it like this:

```
"/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/+"
```

[Found here](https://html5-tutorial.net/form-validation/validating-email/) 
"self validating email html" google search